# Coplanarity condition for two lines given in general form

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I tried searching the below on MSE site but didn't find any useful answer to the below question .

Prove that the line of intersection of the planes $a_1+b_1+c_1+d_1=0, a_2+b_2+c_2+d_2=0 $  is coplanar with the line of intersection of the planes $a_3+b_3+c_3+d_3=0  \;,\;a_4+b_4+c_4+d_4=0 $ iff
$$det\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
a_1&b_1&c_1&d_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2&d_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3&d_3\\
a_4&b_4&c_4&d_4
\end{array}\right]=0$$

Comment: What happens to the intersection lines when "the volume" of the tetrahedron given by the four planes vanishes?

Comment: Thanks @Jan-MagnusØkland , this works , you are the best.